# RichFaces autocomplete input not correctly send to Bean before form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, jsf, autocomplete, richfaces

I'm using JSF 2.0 with a RichFaces automplete for a search form. When I choose a value from autocomplete or manually type in a value it's not set before the submit event in the Bean through

```
value="#{pageController.searchTerm}"
```

After pressing the Link to submit the form wrong values are passed to a modal window.
After trying like onblur, onchange, onselecteditem and google I have no clue why this happens, any ideas? I just want to select an item and when I press enter it should be sent to the Bean (@Named
@RequestScoped) and then the form submit event should start.
Also

```
<a4j:ajax event="change" execute="#{pageController.searchTerm}"/>
```

didn't solve it.

my search form

```
<h:form id="searchForm">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <rich:message for="autocomplete" ajaxRendered="true"/>
        <rich:autocomplete
                id="autocomplete"
                mode="cachedAjax"
                required="true"
                requiredMessage="value required"
                value="#{pageController.searchTerm}"
                autocompleteMethod="#{autoCompleteBean.autocomplete}">
            <f:validateLength minimum="1"/>
            <a4j:ajax event="change" render="modal-title"/>
        </rich:autocomplete>
    <a4j:commandLink
        styleClass="btn-search"
        render="modal-title"
        oncomplete="$('#modal').modal('show');">
        <h:graphicImage styleClass="btn-search" value="resources/img/magnifying_glass.svg"/>
    </a4j:commandLink>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

the jQuery function to load the modal when enter is used in autocomplete to submit the form.

```
$('#searchForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();        
    $('#modal').modal('show'); 
});
```

and the PageController.java

```
public String getSearchTerm() {
    return "";
}

public void setSearchTerm(String searchTerm) {      
    Values.selectedTerm = searchTerm;
}
```

Comment: Is `value="#{pageController.searchTerm}"` supposed to set `searchWKN`? Those aren't the same.

Comment: @EmilSierżęga sorry, forgot to debrand. yes it's the same name in the code, double checked that so it's not a naming thing...

Comment: Why your getter look like this? Did you try to use normal getter?

Comment: @EmilSierżęga yes I tried, this is just to have an empty input field from the starting point of the user

Comment: If this is view scope bean then it will be empty.

Comment: It's Named and RequestScoped